# How to set Session variable in Node.js with Angular.js and MongoDb

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have an issue to Set session variable in node.js, we are using MongoDb in backend and Angular.js in frontend.

Getting error
Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must
 be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

Please guide me.

Comment: What do you expect from us, if you even have not showed any code...

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use cookie parser, express session, mongodb as session storage, it's quite easy to configure in express.

in your express configuration:

```
var session = require('express-session'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({
        session: session
    });

module.exports = function(db) {
var app = express();
    // CookieParser should be above session
        var cp =cookieParser;
        app.use(cp());

        // Express MongoDB session storage
        var mStore = new mongoStore({
                db: db.connection.db,
                collection: 'sessions'
            });

        app.use(session({
            secret: 'any random string',
            store: mStore,
            cookie: {httpOnly: false}, //optional
            key:config.'connect.sid',
        }));
};
```

where db is your db instance (it could be mongoose)

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://your.ip/database.name');
```

you can override all the configurations suggested.

Comment: Thank you @jack.the.ripper. As I am new in node.js , getting error at key:config.'connect.sid', Can you please explain?